# How can I add DataContext to the xaml of a usercontrol?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I've tried to set in my usercontrol:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData ListItemDemoData.xaml}"
```

But Visual Studio states that it cannot find `ListItemDemoData`, not `ListItemDemoData.xaml` but just the `ListItemDemoData`.

Strange, did I do it wrong?

Comment: Where is ListItemDemoData.xaml located? In the same folder? Design data is extremely buggy in VS :/

Comment: it is the very same folder yes

Comment: Have you checked the Build Action for ListItemDemoData.xaml? It should be set to **DesignData**. Also, you can try to declare it like so: `d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=./ListItemDemoData.xaml}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it on code behind.
I have a usercontrol used to show a large image. The name of my control is ImageViewer. Now I have to bind the image source. So, I created a dependency property like

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSourceValue", typeof(string), typeof(ImageViewer),
       new PropertyMetadata(ValueChanged));

    public string ImageSourceValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the value of ImageSourceValue is changed or set.
    /// </summary>
    public static void ValueChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Get out of a static and into the instance ASAP.
        ImageViewer control = (ImageViewer)sender;
        control.ValueChanged();

    }

    private void ValueChanged()
    {
        //The value of ImageSourceValue is set at the time calling user control from your page.
        this.ImageSource = ImageSourceValue;

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
```

I have used a converter at the time the value is bind to the image control which converts string image path to  bitmapimage object. string ImageSource can be changed to BitmapImage type. and the conversion can be done when the value of ImageSourceValue is assigned to ImageSource.